# The Witcher 2 freezes at the end of chapter 2's cutscene

Tags: technical-issues, the-witcher-2

I'm currently playing The Witcher 2 Enhanced Edition and I've made it to the end of chapter 2, where Geralt is on his way to Loc Muinne.

Everything runs just fine until the narration from Dandelion ends and the game just freezes. Is it possible I'm missing some video file? Has this happened to anybody else?

I've tried reinstalling it, changing my video settings to lowest, and making sure my vid card has the latest drivers

here are my specs:
Windows 7 x64
6gb DDR2 
Q6600 2.4 ghz quad core
Nvidia geforce 8800 GT

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Contact the publisher of the game for technical support.  You have no provided enough information in order to even guess what the problem is.

Comment: Check to see if the game made a save. Often if the game crashes, it would have made a save before hand which, when loaded, takes you to the next chapter (As the save is a "change of chapter autosave")

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace the cut scene movie to move forward (it's probably corrupted). You can take the cut scene from Vernon Roche way, rename it like the one from Iorveth and launch the game again. Once past the cut scene save your game and you can put back the original files. You have to replace the file `load_a2_a3_i.usm` with `load_a2_a3_r.usm`, renaming the last one like the first one.